# How can I change two properties of an anchor element?

Tags: javascript, href

I have these two variables:

```
var a_link = "someLink.com";
var a_text = "Some url text";
```

I'm trying to insert these two variables into an anchor tag. Like this:

```html
<a href="a_link">a_text</a>
```

Here's what I tried so far:

```html
<a href="javascript:window.open(a_link);">
```

How can I change the `a_link` and the `a_text` to the corresponding variables?

Answer (score 0):

**What you're trying to do can be achieved by DOM manipulation.**

Basicly: you have an anchor element `<a>` with two variables: the `href` and the inner HTML. You just need to find the anchor element and change these properties to the corresponding variables.

```
var a_link = "someLink.com";
var a_text = "Some url text";

var anchor = document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
anchor.href = a_link; 
anchor.innerHTML = a_text;
```

The `[0]` you see after the `document.getElementsByTagName("a")` is there to state that we're looking for the first anchor element. If you were trying to change, say, the third `<a>` you'd use `[2]`.

You can read more about DOM Manipulation [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp).

Comment: set equal to `innerHTML` not parentheses `=` not `()` and also add `http://` or `https://` before the url name if they isn't exist the browser won't move him to that website it's will consider him as a relative url and will move him to url at his host

Comment: @JS_INF you're right. I edited my answer to display the right innerHTML usage.

Comment: @JS_INF about the `http://` and `https://` issue: you're also right. I, however, used the variables that were given in the question for clarity.

Comment: I am using this in a column of cells in a large table. Can i write it like this:


`<td>
 <a target="_blank" id="link_260"></a>;     
 <script>
  let link260 = document.getElementById('link_260'); 
  link260.href = url_260;        
  link260.innerHTML = urltxt_260;      
 </script> 
</td>`